# Interrupt with KL25Z board using KDS

Tags: c++, c, embedded, microcontroller

I am programming a microcontroller using Kinetis Design Studio(KDS) and i want to implement an interrupt such that at anytime during runtime if a specific I/O pin has a "high" level the microcontroller should stop working until the pin is back to "low" . 
Any ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest starting by reading the data sheet and reference manuals of your particular MCU to determine how to configure a suitable pin level interrupt, then reading up on how to set define interrupt handlers in your compiler/library and revise your question with specific details if you get stuck. I'd bet you can even dig out some tutorials with a bit of Googling. You may also want to elaborate on what "stop working" means in this context (stop the main CPU from executing the main loop, halt peripheral clock, go to a low-power sleep mode, burn up, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code from free scale forum

https://www.element14.com/community/community/designcenter/kinetis_kl2_freedom_board/blog/2015/08/21/kinetis-design-studio-30-kinetis-sdk-12-processor-expert-using-frdm-kl43z-quick-tutorial-on-gpio-interrupt-toggling-led-using-button-with-interrupt-logic

or

below is an usart interrupt code you can modify it

```
/* p6_4.c UART0 Receive using interrupt */

/* This program modifies p4_2.c to use interrupt to handle the UART0 receive.
   Receiving any key from terminal emulator (TeraTerm) of the host PC to the UART0 on Freescale FRDM-KL25Z board.
   UART0 is connected to openSDA debug agent and has a virtual connection to the host PC COM port.
   Launch TeraTerm on a PC and hit any key.
   The LED program from P2_7 of Chapter 2 is used to turn on the tri-color LEDs according to the key received.
   By default in SystemInit(), FLL clock output is 41.94 MHz.
   Setting BDH=0, BDL=0x17, and OSR=0x0F yields 115200 Baud. */

#include <MKL25Z4.H>

void UART0_init(void);
void delayMs(int n);
void LED_init(void);
void LED_set(char value);
int i=0;
int main (void) {
    __disable_irq();        /* global disable IRQs */
    UART0_init();
    LED_init();
    __enable_irq();         /* global enable IRQs */

    while (1) { 
        /* UART0 receive is moved to interrupt handler*/
    }
}

/* UART0 interrupt handler */
void UART0_IRQHandler(void) 
{
    char c;

    c = UART0->D;           /* read the char received */
    LED_set(c);             /* and use it to set LEDs */
}

/* initialize UART0 to receive at 115200 Baud */
void UART0_init(void) 
    {
    SIM->SCGC4 |= 0x0400;    /* enable clock for UART0 */
    SIM->SOPT2 |= 0x04000000;   /* use FLL output for UART Baud rate generator */
    UART0->C2 = 0;          /* turn off UART0 while changing configurations */
    UART0->BDH = 0x00;
    UART0->BDL = 0x17;      /* 115200 Baud */
    UART0->C4 = 0x0F;       /* Over Sampling Ratio 16 */
    UART0->C1 = 0x00;       /* 8-bit data */
    UART0->C2 = 0x24;       /* enable receive and receive interrupt*/
    NVIC->ISER[0] |= 0x00001000;    /* enable INT12 (bit 12 of ISER[0]) */

    SIM->SCGC5 |= 0x0200;    /* enable clock for PORTA */
    PORTA->PCR[1] = 0x0200; /* make PTA1 UART0_Rx pin */
}

/* initialize all three LEDs on the FRDM board */
void LED_init(void)
{
    SIM->SCGC5 |= 0x400;        /* enable clock to Port B */
    SIM->SCGC5 |= 0x1000;       /* enable clock to Port D */
    PORTB->PCR[18] = 0x100;     /* make PTB18 pin as GPIO */
    PTB->PDDR |= 0x40000;       /* make PTB18 as output pin */
    PTB->PSOR |= 0x40000;       /* turn off red LED */
    PORTB->PCR[19] = 0x100;     /* make PTB19 pin as GPIO */
    PTB->PDDR |= 0x80000;       /* make PTB19 as output pin */
    PTB->PSOR |= 0x80000;       /* turn off green LED */
    PORTD->PCR[1] = 0x100;      /* make PTD1 pin as GPIO */
    PTD->PDDR |= 0x02;          /* make PTD1 as output pin */
    PTD->PSOR |= 0x02;          /* turn off blue LED */
}

/* turn on or off the LEDs according to bit 2-0 of the value */
void LED_set(char value)
{

    if (value=='c') 
        {           /* use bit 1 of value to control green LED */
        PTB->PCOR = 0x80000;    /* turn on green LED */
s       }
        if (~(value=='c') ) 
        {           /* use bit 1 of value to control green LED */
      PTB->PSOR = 0x80000;    /* turn off green LED */

        }


}
```